# How to connect to acomba odbc from docker container

Tags: docker, powershell, odbc

I have successfully been able to connect to a acomba database using the odbc from a test asp.net project with the following code.

```cs
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = "Driver={Acomba ODBC Driver};AcombaEXE=" + acombaAppFolder + ";Dbq=" + acombaDBFolder + ";Uid=" + acombaDBUser + ";Pwd=" + acombaDBPassword + ";VersionSDK=27;PassWnd=0";

connection.Open();
```

Howerver, when I do try the same from another project that runs in a windows docker container, I am getting the following error:

`System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException : 'ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'`.

I then tought that maybe I needed to install/register the odbc driver inside the docker container. I logged inside the container and ran the following command:
`Start-Process AcoODBC.exe -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput c:\temp\example-output.txt -ArgumentList "/S" -PassThru`
The process appears to run but never ends unless I do "ctrl +c".

How to fix the error and be able to connect to the odbc from the docker project?

[image: Result of the powershell command]